# How do I change the AutoSave Interval for Word and Powerpoint 2013 using Powershell?

Tags: windows, excel, powershell, scripting, ms-office

Im using powershell to script and change AutoRecover Save Interval to 2 or 3 minutes. I got it to work on Excel 2013, but can not seem to make it work on Word or PowerPoint.

This is for Excel 2013:

```
$a = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$a.AutoRecover.Time = 2
```

That is for Excel and it works. This is what I have for Word and PowerPoint:

```
$a = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$b = New-Object -comobject Word.Application
$c = New-Object -comobject PowerPoint.Application
## Enable Autorecover if it happens to be disabled
$a.AutoRecover.Enabled = True
$b.AutoRecover.Enabled = True
$c.AutoRecover.Enabled = True
## Change the timer
$a.AutoRecover.Time = 2
$b.Options.SaveInterval = 1
$c.Options.SaveInterval = 1'
```

**$a.AutoRecover.Time = 2** which is the Excel works fine. But the same code does not work for Word or PowerPoint.

Its the last 2 lines that do not work. I do not know the path to the AutoRecover Timer.

Any help?